# Displaying empty rows in ListView for 4.1.1v device -Android

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

In **custom ListView** all rows are empty! .. the data not appear! I do not know where the problem actually, I execute the same .apk file on many devices, however, it is run correctly on all of them except android device with version 4.1.1. Really I can't know where is the problem for apk to run on one device and not on the other one?! (this will lead me to mad)..

**The custom ListView code** (I am sure the problem is not in code, cause it is run on the other devices and data appear on ListView):

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public String title[];
public String description[];
public String curr[];
public int size,fontsize;
public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public showAccounts accounts;

public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context,String[] title, String[] description, String[] curr) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.accounts=new showAccounts();
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.curr = curr;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgViewLogo;
    TextView txtViewTitle;
    TextView txtViewDescription;
    TextView txtViewcurr;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    //Define the size of layout 
    size=accounts.getsize();
    fontsize=accounts.getfont();

    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.accountlist, null);

        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.txtViewTitle.setWidth(size*2); 
        holder.txtViewTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,fontsize);

        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setWidth(size);   
        holder.txtViewDescription.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,fontsize);

        holder.txtViewcurr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.txtViewcurr.setWidth(size/2);   
        holder.txtViewcurr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,fontsize);

        if ( position % 2 == 0 ){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#96c4fa"));

        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e9e9e9"));
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        if ( position % 2 == 0 ){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#96c4fa"));

        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e9e9e9"));
        }
    }

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
    holder.txtViewcurr.setText(curr[position]);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**accountlist.xml code**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="right"

 />
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="right"

 />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="right"

        />

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/wuser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

- I attempt to execute the apk on real device via Eclipse to see where is the problem (BUT the device does not appear in list).
- I do not think that the problem in code, since the same code for apk run on other devices
- Or the problem maybe related to usage space for apk? I do not know actually!
- You can see please the two images that explain my problem.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated,

**Edit**

my problem was solved! I just reset the device and everything goes well! Really, before, I do not think that the viruses can cause like these problems, such affects to other applications,etc. However, its good to note and know that after this long time to solve this problem!

Comment: Can you tell the android version of those devices on which data is coming ?

Comment: @Maheera, first you check that title is empty or not.

Comment: yes, 4.0.3, 4.3 , 4.2.2 etc. BUT the version of device that can't display date 4.1.1 ?!

Comment: @ Sweta Sharma, yes I check that there are data BUT it does not display on ListView !

Comment: Check values of `size` and `fontsize`. They could be zero.

Comment: @ erakitin , yes please I check them, the problem not in them ?!

Comment: did you debug the code ? you can check that whether data are filled in each array or not.

Comment: Please post your accountlist.xml

Comment: @Dig yes please, the code run perfectly on virtual device (emulator) BUT my problem with some of real devices, I attempt to connect between real device and Eclipse BUT this doesn't work with me, the device not listed on  Eclipse running Android devices!

Comment: @erakitin , yes please you can see the Edit!

Comment: @Maheera Jazi Device is not listed, may be you have not installed required driver (eg. samsung usb device driver). In emulator, running 4.1.1, you can debug too.

Comment: @Dig yes please, I download the requirements BUT it seems the problem in my computer or Eclipse version (I do not know actually where yet)!

Comment: @Maheera Jazi is your data coming in emulator running on 4.1.1 ?

Comment: @Dig, I do not have one on Android SDK Manager, BUT I tried on 4.1.2 version and it works well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in setting the width of text views in the correct way and the same thing for the text size. So, try to delete or comment the code that is related in setting widths and sizes such these lines of code

```
 holder.txtViewTitle.setWidth(size*2); 
 holder.txtViewTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,fontsize);
```

After that run the code over your particular simulator or device, then you will see the appearance of your texts. Note that (from my point of view) it is wrong to fix the size of font and the width of the views, so you have to find a way to adapt the sizes based on the screen width of the devices.

Comment: yes, thanks for your answer, but really I test all of that (with no hope!). For your note please, sure, their values are not FIXED their change based on the width of the screen, I need to give one view size more than other views cause of that I send the size value (that changed based on the device screen width). I am still try to discover where is the problem. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: finally, my problem was solved! I just reset the device and everything goes well! Really, before, I do not think that the viruses can cause like these problems, such affects to other applications,etc. However, its good to note and know that  after this long time to solve this problem! thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that your problem solved. Yes, viruses do a lot of things in devices and I think you have gained a good experience about such kinds of problems. Okay Well Done :)

Answer (score 0):

First you initialize variable title, description and curr.

For eg. `this.title=new title[title.length];`

Same as above initialize all the array variable.

Comment: yes, actually I do that in public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context,String[] title, String[] description, String[] curr) ... mmm

Comment: @MaheeraJazi try this - yourlist.invalidateviews();

Comment: @ Sweta Sharma, yes please  I try this BUT with no change :( !

Comment: finally, my problem was solved! I just reset the device and everything goes well! Really, before, I do not think that the viruses can cause like these problems, such affects to other applications,etc. However, its good to note and know that after this long time to solve this problem! thanks.

Comment: wc...its my pleasure @MaheeraJazi